# TCP/IP model: Interface Layer for mobile broadband

Tags: gsm, tcp, gprs, osi

The Interface layer protocol (Link-layer of OSI model) IEEE802.3 describes Ethernet and IEEE 802.11 describes WiFi. However it seems that there is no standardised link layer protocol for communication via GPRS/3G/4G.

Hence, what link layer protocols are being used when establishing mobile data connectivity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The protocol stack is well defined within the 3GPP specs and there are quite a few examples if you search for '3GPP protocol stack'. Most look something like:

[image]

This is from a pack on the ietf site which also explains some of the layers so may be of interest to you:

- https://www.ietf.org/proceedings/48/SLIDES/pilc-wcdma/sld006.htm